# MySql display name & data for users with a score of 10 or more, but only name for those with a score < 10

Tags: php, mysql

From a table [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94ef32/1) how can I select and display name and data, for users who have a score of 10 or more, but display only the name for users who have a score of < 10, without using php in between?

I know I can do this in php (and I do), But is there a pure mysql way to do it?

**Php way**

```
if($score >=10) {echo $name $data} else {echo $name}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly via query using `IF` or `CASE` (*CASE to be more RDBMS friendly*)

```
SELECT  Name,
        IF(score < 10, '', score) score,
        IF(score < 10, '', data) data
FROM    json
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*using `IF`*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94ef32/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*using `CASE`*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94ef32/7)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦═══════╦══════════════════╗
║  NAME  ║ SCORE ║       DATA       ║
╠════════╬═══════╬══════════════════╣
║ Peter  ║    50 ║ Peter's Foo data ║
║ James  ║    10 ║ James's Foo data ║
║ John   ║       ║                  ║
║ Andrew ║       ║                  ║
╚════════╩═══════╩══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Can we do it all in one line, like `IF(score < 10, '', score, data) info`... Something like that.

Comment: do you want the columns to be concatenated? can you show me your desired output?

Comment: My desired output is simlar to what you've displayed here. Problem is, there are severals columns, and it'll be a large number of if's or case's.